# Count records by month starting with July to June

Tags: t-sql

We use calendar months July - June instead of January - December. I have a query that counts each record by month and adds the previous month's records to the new month Jan to Fab. Is there a way to start with the month of July and add July's counts to August and August to October and so on...

Here is the query:

```
SELECT ReviewType,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 1 THEN ReviewType END) AS Jan,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 2 THEN ReviewType END) AS Feb,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 3 THEN ReviewType END) AS Mar,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 4 THEN ReviewType END) AS Apr,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 5 THEN ReviewType END) AS May,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 6 THEN ReviewType END) AS Jun,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 7 THEN ReviewType END) AS Jul,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 8 THEN ReviewType END) AS Aug,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 9 THEN ReviewType END) AS Sep,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 10 THEN ReviewType END) AS Oct,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 11 THEN ReviewType END) AS Nov,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 12 THEN ReviewType END) AS Dec,
       COUNT(ReviewType) AS Result
FROM ALAN.dbo.qryPeakReviews 
WHERE fiscalYear = 1819
GROUP BY ReviewType;
```

Here is the output:

```
ReviewType  Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec Result
1           0   17  46  57  67  72  72  72  83  87  93  94  94
2           0   2   22  27  31  34  34  37  43  48  48  48  48
3           0   1   16  28  34  37  37  39  45  47  49  49  49
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 6 to all the months and get the remainder of the division of the result with 12:

```
SELECT ReviewType,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN (MONTH(dateCompleted) + 6) % 12 = 1 THEN ReviewType END) AS Jul,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN (MONTH(dateCompleted) + 6) % 12 BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN ReviewType END) AS Aug,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN (MONTH(dateCompleted) + 6) % 12 BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN ReviewType END) AS Sep,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN (MONTH(dateCompleted) + 6) % 12 BETWEEN 1 AND 4 THEN ReviewType END) AS Oct,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN (MONTH(dateCompleted) + 6) % 12 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN ReviewType END) AS Nov,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN (MONTH(dateCompleted) + 6) % 12 BETWEEN 1 AND 6 THEN ReviewType END) AS Dec,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN (MONTH(dateCompleted) + 6) % 12 BETWEEN 1 AND 7 THEN ReviewType END) AS Jan,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN (MONTH(dateCompleted) + 6) % 12 BETWEEN 1 AND 8 THEN ReviewType END) AS Feb,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN (MONTH(dateCompleted) + 6) % 12 BETWEEN 1 AND 9 THEN ReviewType END) AS Mar,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN (MONTH(dateCompleted) + 6) % 12 BETWEEN 1 AND 10 THEN ReviewType END) AS Apr,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN (MONTH(dateCompleted) + 6) % 12 BETWEEN 1 AND 11 THEN ReviewType END) AS May,
       COUNT(ReviewType) AS Jun,
       COUNT(ReviewType) AS Result
FROM ALAN.dbo.qryPeakReviews 
WHERE fiscalYear = 1819
GROUP BY ReviewType;
```

I changed the inequality check with `BETWEEN 1 AND ...` because June is calculated as `0` and should not be included.
Also there is no reason to count anything special for the last month June. It is the total of all the year.